# How can I delete cookies on my website that I did not create?

Tags: http, cookies

My website is 
http://www.florida-voters.org/UNI/UNIMain.html

My website contains no cookie saving code. I don't even know how to write PHP or HTML code that uses cookies, however, over time the first name, middle name, last name and street name on my main page stores then displays all the previous typed in values for each text field. I only want to save the cookie for the street name, not the first, middle or last name text boxes and if that is not possible then I don't want my website to save any cookies at all. How do I do this?

Tom Kelly.

Comment: That is probably the "*browser* autofill / autocomplete", not 'cookies'. See eg. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893 (If so, the question might become: 'How can browser autocomplete be suppressed for certain fields?')

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am going to look into that. Tom Kelly.